# Where do I connect a road to?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I'm trying to plan out my new fortress before I start construction, but I'm not sure where the road must go. I'd like to ensure that I don't need to construct a road right across the entire map. Is there any particular edge that wagons always arrive from? Can they come from any edge? Or is it simply the case that wherever I build it is where they will come from?

Comment: I know I don't need one, but I'm quite fastidious and watching a wagon bumble along, bouncing off trees, just sets my teeth on edge.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't *need* to have a road connected for wagons to arrive, but if you do, wagons will use the road, and arrive on the edge of the map wherever the road connects. This can make it easier to defend incoming caravans against sieges and ambushes.

Answer (score 4):

You actually don't need roads to support Trade Wagons, as long as they have a 3x3 path to your depot, you'll be fine (you can even toggle the wagon pathing display, if you need to).

You may eventually need to build a road if you want to make your fortress the eventual mountainhome, but again, there's no specifications other than, "have road connected to map edge", so there is no preferred edge there either.

Comment: assuming that I only want wagons to use roads, is there anything I can do? (short of building and raising drawbridges all around the map to prevent them spawning)?

Comment: @Ian As per SaintWaco's answer, wagons will spawn in on the roads -- so if you have at least *one* road at the map edge, you should know where the wagons will enter from, and can go from there.

Comment: Paved roads prevent trees from growing over your wagon path, which can be disastrous if it is your only 3x3 path and you are waiting to trade for supplies.